# error: horizontal dimensions mismatch (4x4 vs 1x4)

Tags: octave

Why there is an error in the below code? I have tried to convert a row of the matrix `B` into a column of it.

```
B=[B 20*B(:,1)]
B =

      1      2      3     20
     10     20     30    200
      7      8      9    140
    100    200    300   2000

B=[B,B(1,:)]
```

error: `horizontal dimensions mismatch (4x4 vs 1x4)`

Comment: what are you actually trying to do with that last command?

Answer (score 1):

B(1,:) is 1x4 as dimensions

```
   1      2      3     20
```

While B is 4x4

```
      1      2      3     20
     10     20     30    200
      7      8      9    140
    100    200    300   2000
```

and you are asking Octave to make a matrix like

```
      1      2      3     20       1      2      3     20
     10     20     30    200
      7      8      9    140
    100    200    300   2000
```

that clearly does not work.